# How can i include mouse over effect for each bar in html 5 chart

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am newbie to html5. I want to include some mouse over function through css or javascript so that when i mouse over particular bar it has to display some message. I dont want to go for some api. pls help me out. Here is my code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){
                var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
                var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
                var value=[180,140,30,340,50,90];
                var width=50;
                var currx=30;
                ctx.fillStyle="red";
                var i = 0;
                var interval = setInterval(function(){
                    if (i == value.length){
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        return;
                    }
                    var h=value[i];
                    ctx.fillRect(currx,canvas.height-h,width,h);
                    currx+=width+10;
                    i++;
                }, 2000);console.log(interval);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    </body>
</html>
```

**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyhmx/)**

Comment: check out [KineticJs](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/). it adds support for event handling for canvas shapes.

Comment: Thanks @EliranMalka. I already know about Kineticjs. But i dont want to go for any other javascript.

Comment: well, that seems like the only option, as canvas shapes do not have a representation in the DOM and can't be served as observer-subjects in a strait-forward fashion (nor can they be references by CSS, for the same reason).

Comment: then it's either roll your own or don't roll at all

Comment: and roll your own meaning  calculate mouse position and then calculate if it is hovering on any of your bars http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Comment: @jakee, please post your comment as an answer, elaborating on this a little, so others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use a library like [KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/) which abstracts the drawable shapes into objects and provides nifty methods for binding them to mouse events. This has the benefit of minimizing the work required by your side, therefore allowing you to concentrate on the functionality itself, and not reinventing the wheel.
2. Roll your own solution, much like someone does when he/she created a library like the one mentioned above. Design some abstraction for your shapes (in this instance some kind of a Bar object) that encompasses the relevant features (notably the x,y,w,h) and on canvas `mousemove-event`, bruteforce through all your bars and calculate whether or not the event mouse position is within a bar or not. Then act accordingly, e.g. redraw the bar in new color. Of course you'll have to handle `mouseout` as well (to color it back and the like).